# Куда положить file.dat в Unity. Чтоб открывать ее через BinaryReader в андроиде и т д?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Делал так в самом юнити, но оказалось с Assets нельзя открывать на андроиде.

```
private string Path;
Path = "Assets/file.dat";
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(Path, FileMode.Open)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому кому интересно как я решил этот вопрос.
В Assets создаем папку Resources (это системная папка нужна для загрузки из нее файлов, объектов, изображений и т.д). Расширение файла меняем с file.dat на file.bytes, путь к файлу указываем как просто название файла, так как загрузка будет происходить уже напрямую с папки Resources. Создаем массив bytes и задаем ей значение с помощю метода Resources.Load(). Проверяем загрузилось ли что либо в bytes. Если он не пустой, то кидаем его в поток памяти MemoryStream и считываем через BinaryReader.

```
private string Path;
Path = "file";
var bytes = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(Path).bytes;
if (bytes != null)
{
   using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
   {
      using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream ))
      {
         //ваш код
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

```cs
private readonly string _path = UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath;
```

Расположение на Android: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files`
Расположение в эдиторе: `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\<companyname>\<productname>`

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Эта строчка - единственная информация, которая нужна 

Comment: Зачем тебе его через ресурсы грузить, когда ты можешь при первом запуске создать этот файл через Create, наполнить его содержимым по дефолту и потом уже как хочешь изменять.

Comment: @KOTlK Ну у меня там большой обьем содержимого, поэтому я держу его отдельно и использую только для считывания. Если бы содержимое уже было прописано в скрипте, было бы бессмысленно выводить в отдельный файл, чтобы потом его же считывать)